# How can I initialize attributes in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So this block of code allows me to initialize a data model

```
 struct MockMessage: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let imageName: String
    let messageText: String
    let isCurrentUser: Bool
}



  let MOCK_MESSAGES: [MockMessage] = [
        .init(id: 0, imageName: "user", messageText: "Hey, what's up?", isCurrentUser: false),
.init(id: iCouldSetANewOne, imageName: iCouldSetANewOne, messageText: iCouldSetANewOne, isCurrentUser: iCouldSetANewOne)]
```

My question is

1- How can I replicate/initialize attributes instead of manually writing the same attributes over and over again

2- How can I modify it, let's say, the default rotation effect is set to a degree: 25 and I'd like to change it.

Example of Image attributes

```
 Image(systemName: tabs[index].image)
                                .frame(height: 20)
                                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-25))
                                .foregroundColor(.yellow).scaleEffect(1.25)
```

Comment: 1) What do you want to accomplish? Can't you create the objects in a loop? 2) How is this related to 1)?

Comment: You have asked two pretty much unrelated questions.  Ask one question per question. The way I approach 1 is to add a static member to the struct - `mockMessages` or create a `Mock` struct with static properties for the various mock data that I need.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to group a commonly used set of modifiers into 1 simple modifier. You can easily do it like this:

```swift
extension View {
    func myStyle() -> some View {
        self
            .frame(...)
            .rotationEffect(...)
            .foregroundColor(...)
    }
}
```

You can even parametrize this function if the values can be different.

About the "changing the rotation effect that is set to 25 degrees" I believe you can have multiple of the same effects, so if you want to rotate some view that is already rotated, just put another `.rotationEffect()` view modifier on top.